# standard scaler reports missing features even though the column for it exists

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use a trained model I'm trying to redo the formatting but after creating dummies I get this error:

```
Feature names seen at fit time, yet now missing:
- Emplacement de la blessure_bras
- Emplacement de la blessure_dos
```

I tried to check the datafreme and it does return the column!

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     1
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    1
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    0
Name: Emplacement de la blessure_bras, dtype: uint8
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model needs two features in order to predict. The DataFrame you are printing only has one column called `Emplacement de la blessure_bras`, hence, you are missing the column `Emplacement de la blessure_dos`.

Comment: no i made a mistake in the post I printed the column not the entire data frame but they both exist

Answer (score 0):

It was a space in the trained model...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).